# Not work trim JQuery

Tags: jquery

Not work trim in JQuery. I can't see mistake:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="this.val($.trim(this.val()));"/>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is a dom reference so it does not have `.val()` method, it has a property `value` which you can use.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="this.value = $.trim(this.value);"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9G8yX/)

or you can access the jQuery wrapper and use .val()

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="$(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));"/>
```

---

But I would recommend against using inline event handlers and suggest adding handlers using script like

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field"/>
```

then

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('input[name="name"]').change(function(){
        this.value = $.trim(this.value);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/edr5Y/)

Comment: But inline event handlers in this situation i am can't use. I am everything use it.

Answer (score 2):

You would not write inline `jQuery` code, also you can not call `val()` on this rather you need `$(this)`. Pass the current object to javascript function using `this`. In javascript function you would jQuery method on object after converting DOM object to jQuery object

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="someFun(this)"/>

function someFun(obj)
{
     $(obj).val($.trim(obj.val()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your code is javascript and `val()` is jquery method

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="$(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="inputsearch field" onchange="$(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));"/>
```